# Memory is not freed in worker after job ends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-management, sidekiq, activerecord-import

Scenario:

I have a job running a process (sidekiq) in production (heroku). The process imports data (CSV) from S3 into a DB model using `activerecord-import` gem. This gem helps to bulk insertion of data. Thus `dbRows` variable sets a considerable amount of memory from all `ActiveRecord` objects stored when iterating CSV lines (all good). Once data is imported (in: `db_model.import dbRows`) `dbRows` is cleared (should be!) and next object is processed.

Such as: (script simplified for better understanding)

```
def import
      ....
      s3_objects.contents.each do |obj|
          @cli.get_object({..., key: obj.key}, target: file) 
          dbRows = []
          csv = CSV.new(file, headers: false)
          while line = csv.shift
              # >> here dbRows grows and grows and never is freed!
              dbRows << db_model.new(
                field1: field1,
                field2: field2,
                fieldN: fieldN
              )
          end
          db_model.import dbRows
          dbRows = nil   # try 1 to freed array
          GC.start   # try 2 to freed memory
      end
      ....
end
```

Issue:

Job memory grows while process runs BUT once the job is done memory does not goes down. It stays forever and ever!

Debugging I found that `dbRows` does not look to be never garbage collected
and I learned about RETAINED objects in and how memory works in rails. Although I did not find yet a way to apply it to solve my problem.

I would like that once the job finished all references set on dbRows are GC and worker memory is freed.

any help appreciated.

UPDATE: I read about `weakref` but I don't know if is would be useful. any insights there?

Comment: Please google for ruby memory bloat; there are dozens of blog posts on this subject. https://www.mikeperham.com/2018/04/25/taming-rails-memory-bloat/ https://www.speedshop.co/2017/12/04/malloc-doubles-ruby-memory.html are two.

Comment: Hi @MikePerham, I installed `heroku-buildpack-jemalloc` but not changes in memory handling. thanks anyway.

Comment: heroku config:set MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2  this will reduce memory bloating.

Comment: if nothing works try https://github.com/resque/resque. its implementation address this known issue of sidekiq. maybe it will suites for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing lines from the CSV in batches, e.g. import lines into the DB 1000 lines at a time so you're not holding onto previous rows, and the GC can collect them. This is good for the database, in any case (and for the download from s3, if you hand `CSV` the IO object from S3.

```rb
s3_io_object = s3_client.get_object(*s3_obj_params).body
csv = CSV.new(s3_io_object, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol)
csv.each_slice(1_000) do |row_batch|
  db_model.import ALLOWED_FIELDS, row_batch.map(&:to_h), validate: false
end
```

Note that I'm not instantiating AR models either to save on memory, and only passing in hashes and telling `activerecord-import` to `validate: false`.

Also, where does the `file` reference come from? It seems to be long-lived.

It's not evident from your example, but is it possible for references to objects are still being held globally by a library or extension in your environment?

Sometimes these things are very difficult to track down, as any code from anywhere that's called (including external library code) could do something like:

Dynamically defining constants, since they never get GC'd

```rb
Any::Module::Or:Class.const_set('NewConstantName', :foo)
```

or adding data to anything referenced/owned by a constant

```rb
SomeConstant::Referenceable::Globally.array << foo # array will only get bigger and contents will never be GC'd
```

Otherwise, the best you can do is use some memory profiling tools, either inside of Ruby (memory profiling gems) or outside of Ruby (job and system logs) to try and find the source.

Comment: HI @Kache thanks for your answer. Actually I know exactly the line that increase memory: when `dbRows << db_model.new(...)`. Reading here: https://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-uses-memory/ I think it is related to how RETAINED objects are treated in rails. But I don't know how to workaround it as I need dbRows to bulk the data in a later state: In `db_model.import dbRows`

Comment: You are not using a constant in your example though, so it doesn't seem like it. How about try importing in batches to see if it helps? I'll add to my answer.